# PHP Function Preg Match pulling second image instead of first

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

Function in my php code:

```
private function get_first_images($html){
    preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $html, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]) && isset($matches[1][0]) && !empty($matches[1][0])){
        return $matches[1][0];
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

is pulling the second image instead of the first.  Here is an example of the xml it is looking at:

```
<![CDATA[
<a href="http://mls-photos.diversesolutions.com/355/1246202/0-full.jpg?15054836" target="_blank"><img src="http://mls-photos.diversesolutions.com/355/1246202/0-medium.jpg?15054836" alt="Property Photo" /></a><br /><br /><img src="http://cdn1.diverse-cdn.com/idx-v2/mls-icons/rein.png" alt="Mls Icon" /><br /><br /><b>3 beds, 2 full, 1 part baths</b><br />Home size: 1,700 sq ft<br />Lot Size: 0 sq ft<br />Property Type: Residential, Residential / Detached<br />MLS Number: 1246202<br />Community: North Norfolk<br />Tract: East Beach<br /><br /><br />Beautiful New Home With Wrap Around Porch, 10 Ft. Ceilings On First Floor, Hardwood Floors, Custom Cabinets, Granite, One Block To The Beach. Real Cedar Shake Exterior. Corner Lot. Carriage House Unfinished. <br /><br />Listed with Keller Williams Realty<br /><hr noshade="noshade" /><br /><b>Brought to you by Virginia Beach Real Estate Team, Keller Williams Realty. Call me today at 757-215-4246, or visit my website at <a href="http://www.vbret.com" target="_blank">www.vbret.com</a>!</b><br /><br /><p>Users of this Site are granted a limited, nonexclusive license to use the Site and its listing content for personal and noncommercial use only.
 </p>
 <p>
 Real Estate Information Network, Inc. (REIN) updates its listings on a daily basis. Data last updated: 12/21/12 7:55 AM PST. Some properties which appear for sale on this website may have subsequently sold or may no longer be available.
 </p>
 <p>
 All Information Deemed Reliable But Not Guaranteed.
 </p>
 <p>
 REIN's listings are based upon data submitted by its Broker Members, and REIN therefore makes no representation or warranty regarding the accuracy of the data. All users of REIN's listings database should confirm the accuracy of the listing information directly with the listing agent. This data and information is protected under Federal Copyright laws. Federal law prohibits, among other acts, the unauthorized copying or alteration of, or preparation of derivative works from, all or any part of copyrighted materials, including certain compilations of data and information. COPYRIGHT VIOLATORS MAYBE SUBJECT TO SEVERE FINES AND PENALTIES UNDER FEDERAL LAW.
 </p><hr noshade="noshade" />
]]>
```

How do I fix it so that it pulls the first image and not the second?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html

Comment: @macek is generally correct, BTW.  Anytime you want to do all but the most trivial HTML parsing, you're better off using something like DOM to work with the structure of the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the + ungreedy :

```
private function get_first_images($html){
    preg_match_all('/<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $html, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]) && isset($matches[1][0]) && !empty($matches[1][0])){
        return $matches[1][0];
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: but doesn't the `[^\'"]` in the pattern have the same effect (making the + not consume too much)?

Comment: no , the dot is evaluated first and the + is greedy by default, it will consume everything then backup at the end to the last src=...

Comment: Silly me, I missed the first '+'. I was looking at the second plus '+', after [^\'"].  You are correct.  Upvote on your answer.